# Finding how many times a given package has been installed

Tags: apt, package-management

Is there any way to see how many times a package in the repos (say, `firefox`) has been installed?

Comment: Which repository? Do you have one of your own?

Comment: multiverse or similar

Comment: Your headline says "downloaded" but the question then says "installed". Which one do you want? They're not the same.

Comment: I changed it. They are nearly the same, though, probably not more than a few percent off.

Comment: How many times it's been installed on to your computer? You mean, how many rounds of installation/uninstallation you've done? Or do you mean how many times globally? From which repository? Which mirror of that repository? Please [edit] and clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the repositories keep track of download counts, but Debian based systems have a (voluntary?) program known as the popularity contest. The Ubuntu popularity contest stats can be found at http://popcon.ubuntu.com/. It tracks installation counts, recency of usage, etc. You might be able to indirectly get the numbers you need from popcon.